# How to find an uncontiguous set of non-empty cells that are hidden in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, excel-interop

I'm using C# for an Excel addin.
I need to find all non-empty cells in a hidden row. These cells are non-contiguous and do not follow a pattern. Here is an example :

[image]

I've tried using Range.SpecialCells :

```
Range rangeToSearch = Excel.ActiveSheet.Rows[row].Cells;

try
{
    Range rangeMatch = rangeToSearch.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas | XlCellType.xlCellTypeValues)

    // Loop over rangeMatch
}
catch (COMException)
{
    // no matches
}
```

And Range.Find :

```
Range rangeToSearch = Excel.ActiveSheet.Rows[row].Cells;
Range rangeMatch = rangeToSearch.Find("*", Type.Missing, XlFindLookIn.xlValues, XlLookAt.xlPart, XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns);

// Check if null then loop using FindNext
```

These methods work just fine on visible rows, but not on the hidden ones.
The only way I know to "trick" the issue is to use Worksheet.UsedRange, however I don't think this is reliable at all, plus it will get the empty cells as well.

Is there a clean and efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If you relay on exception handling to detect a positive or negative situation in your code, you should consider other methods. Exception handling is resource and time consuming. It is usually considered a "code smell"

Comment: I do agree. I do not usually relay on exception handling. In this particular case, Range.SpecialCells will throw a COMException when it doesn't find anything so it seems to me that it is mandatory to show this, to preserve consistency in this example. Also I did not want to overload my topic with more exception handling. Range.Find was my first approach and I only tried using SpecialCells because it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. i will give you a way to output  cells from a non-contiguous set of cells(called Areas in the Excel model) to a List

```
    static Excel.Range GetCellsWithValues(Excel.Range row)
    {
        Excel.Range r = null;
        // Cut out unneccessary calcs by using only the intersection of the Row with the UsedRange
        Excel.Range usedRow = row.Application.Intersect(row, row.Worksheet.UsedRange);
        if (usedRow != null)
        {
            foreach (Excel.Range cell in usedRow)
                if (cell.Value2 != null)  //if non-empty unite to r
                    r = (r == null) ? cell : row.Application.Union(r, cell);
        }
        return r;  // a non-contiguous Range will have Areas with blocks of contiguous Ranges
    }

    static List<Excel.Range> GetCellListFromAreas(Excel.Range r)
    {   // this will unwrap the cells from non-contiguous range into a List
        // choose other collections for your use
        List<Excel.Range> cellList = new List<Excel.Range>();
        Excel.Areas areas = r?.Areas;

        if (areas != null)
        { 
            // Unwrap the Areas (blocks of contiguous cells)
            foreach (Excel.Range area in areas)
                foreach (Excel.Range cell in area)
                    cellList.Add(cell);  // add each cell in each contiguous block
        }
        return cellList;
    }
```

Call like so:

`List<Excel.Range> cellList = GetCellListFromAreas(GetCellsWithValues(Excel.ActiveSheet.Rows[row]));`

Though we prefer if you qualify sheets explicitly by Sheet name rather than ActiveSheet.

Note also, you could dispense with the Collection/List of Excel Ranges(cells), and put the Values in an array or whatever....

So obviously you could put straight into a List first time around and cut out the steps of Union into ranges than unwrapping the Areas. So like:

```
    static List<Excel.Range> GetCellListWithValues(Excel.Range row)
    {
        List<Excel.Range> cellList = new List<Excel.Range>();
        Excel.Range r = null;
        Excel.Range usedRow = row.Application.Intersect(row, row.Worksheet.UsedRange);
        if (usedRow != null)
        {
            foreach (Excel.Range cell in usedRow)
                if (cell.Value2 != null)
                    cellList.Add(cell);
        }
        return cellList;
    }
```

Comment: Hello MacroMarc, thank you very much for your super clear answer ! I tested it and it does work indeed. I had a kind of similar solution on my side actually. I wished I had a way to retrieve all the cells I needed directly without having to check each cells if there is a value inside. However your solution works and answers the question. Plus, since it is very similar to what I have, I guess you can't avoid the final iteration. I'm marking your answer as correct. Thank you for your time and this very well explained answer !

Comment: glad to help. Thanks